# How can I configure SMPlayer to work with my keyboard media keys?

Tags: smplayer

My media keys (e.g. <kbd>FN+F11</kbd> for play/pause) work with other media players such as VLC. However, they do not work with SMPlayer by default.

How do I have to configure SMPlayer to make it work with my media keys?

Comment: I've filed a bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/smplayer/bugs/801/

Answer (score 1):

You may need to disable the multimedia shortcuts in the Ubuntu settings. Otherwise SMPlayer won't receive the press events for those keys.

[image]

Comment: This might work but it's not a proper integration, isn't it?